# Is there a way to "refresh" the terminal/iTerm without closing the current sessions?

Tags: terminal, nativescript, iterm

I just updated my xcode command line tool in my iTerm2 and it seems like I need to restart my iTerm to put that to work, since when I try to use

```
tns build ios
```

command to build my nativescript project for iOS, it always echos back

```
xcodebuild execution failed. Make sure that you have latest Xcode and tools installed.
```

which shouldn't be true.
However, I am having a session that's currently running to upload a huge file to my cloud drive which has spent 7 hours to have uploaded 37%, and it doesn't support resume uploading from a break-point.

So, is there any way to refresh the terminal without closing the active session?

Thanks guys

Comment: Maybe `ctrl + L`   ?

Comment: @nbari Thanks, I think that is just clear the screen, but I tried it anyway. Didn't work...

Comment: any solution? my php code also having the same issue

Comment: @Shiro Maybe try source your profile file like `source ~/.bash_profile`. I later found that it may refresh the environment. See if that works

Comment: er.. source actually same like restart, it is kind not convenient, my previous iTerms does not have this issue.

Comment: @nbari `ctrl + L` worked for me. In my case it was a timed-out ssh session

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Not trying to steal answers here.  But the answer is in the comment by @BillyChen

```
source ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.zsh_profile or source ~/.zshrc
```

It depends on what shell you're using to pick up the proper profile.  Some use a common .profile as well

```
source ~/.profile
```

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work for me

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: This solution was already given in Sean Burton's answer.

Answer (score -1):

To completely clear the iterm2 terminal (in case you're using that esp. in Ventura), I only see Edit -> Clear Buffer `(cmd+k)`.

The `control+L` only does the equivalent of a `clear` which doesn't help me most of the time since I may have to run a command with long output and want only that output in the terminal buffer.